# How can I create a database browser on a Rails site idiomatically?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I'm trying to make an interactive web database browser as a component in a Rails website. What is the most idiomatic way to implement this in Rails? Even though I've worked with Active Record, I'm not sure the best way to create a searchable table of database records where you can select filters, sort by field, and view a variable number of records per page as specified by the user.

Basically, something like this: http://www.drugbank.ca/mesh

Are there any thoughts on how I should go about setting this up? I gave ActiveAdmin a try, but the interface is meant to be public; not just for site administrators.

Comment: Like [Active Admin](http://activeadmin.info)?

Comment: This looks awesome - exactly what I have in mind. However, can it be used to render that kind of interface in the website itself? It looks like the purpose of it is to generate an administrative back-end rather than something that faces the public.

Comment: After digging around a bit it looks like it'll be perfect for my needs. Thanks

Comment: You can customize it but it's intended for administration (hence the name). I don't know how "safe" it is.

Comment: might also look at something like ransack gem (https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack)  as opposed to just putting active admin in front.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few gems like this. Check out: https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/rails_admin_interfaces.

Comment: Perfect - I think I'm going to go with Active Admin like @Stefan recommended.

Comment: These admin interfaces don't seem to be well-suited for things that are public-facing. Any other suggestions?